# Building Chainlink External Adapter for Binance Withdrawals

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, adapter, ethereum

I have already made an attempt to build the external adapter but unfortunately, I keep running into the error: "You are not authorized to execute this request"

If you want to know how to exactly build one there are the following resources (basically the same material but different format):

- https://blog.chain.link/build-and-use-external-adapters/ (blogpost)
- https://youtu.be/65NhO5xxSZc (video)

In the resources above a template is used in NodeJS:
https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template

And this is the repo to my own attempt (with error). I just modified the index.js file:
https://github.com/gvandriel/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template

Then start the server with

- yarn (install dependencies)
- yarn start

Open up another terminal and paste the following to post a withdrawal request:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ "id": 0, "data": { "asset": "USDT", "address": "0xe66273cC443F774653E885496f76b486F956B47F", "amount": 10 } }'
```

**Please note** that since you are doing a withdrawal from Binance you need to enable that in your account API settings and set the restricted IP address. Moreover, I believe you can only withdraw funds from an address that you previously have withdrawn to. Also don't forget to update the .env_sample file with your own keys

#### What does work in the code?

We know that the totalstring at line 58 is working since we tested it outside the external adapter. Moreover we also know that the header with X-MBX-APIKEY is working. Thus we believe that the error consists in the following:

```
Requester.request(config, customError)
    .then((response) => {
      // It's common practice to store the desired value at the top-level
      // result key. This allows different adapters to be compatible with
      // one another.
      response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data, [
        "msg",
      ]);
      callback(response.status, Requester.success(jobRunID, response));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      callback(500, Requester.errored(jobRunID, error));
    });
```

The bug might also be somewhere else in the code so make sure to check the modified index.js file here:
https://github.com/gvandriel/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template

Comment: Not sure if it's part of the error message you're getting, but you're calling `Requester.validateResultNumber()` on a value that's expected to be a string. Consider using `getResult()` instead.

Comment: @JonasHals, thank you for your comment. Indeed it is better to use getResult() but unfortunately, this doesn't solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your [index.js file](https://github.com/gvandriel/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/blob/master/index.js), you are setting the params and config objects:

```js
  const params = {
    asset,
    address,
    amount,
    recvWindow,
    timestamp,
    signature,
  };

  const config = {
    method: "post",
    url,
    headers: {
      "X-MBX-APIKEY": process.env.API_key,
    },
  };
```

However, `params` is never included into `config`. Also, it seems you want to send these params as POST data. Consider renaming the `params` object to `data` ([Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)), and append `data` in your `config`:

```js
  const config = {
    method: "post",
    url,
    headers: {
      "X-MBX-APIKEY": process.env.API_key,
    },
    data
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, 
Thank you so much for your help. I have adjusted to code and now get a status code 200. However, unfortunately I don't see any actual withdrawals in my Binance account.
This seems really weird to me. Maybe you can try it with your Binance account? If you can me your ether address I can send you some USDT.